# How to show sum using LINQ statement in Grid view of the MVC app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I developing the MVC application.

I am stuck in LINQ Syntax.

I wan to show the sum of List Items in index view of parent.
Please check code below.

In Model I have two classes.

```
   public class StockAdjustment
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public List<StockAdjustmentItem> StockAdjustmentItems { get; set; }     
                 public int SumOfStockAdjustmentItemQuantity
                {
                get 
           { 
                if (this.StockAdjustmentItems != null)
                {
                return this.StockAdjustmentItems.Sum(s=>s.OriginalQuantity);
                     }
             return 0;
            }
        }
            }

            public class StockAdjustmentItem
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public int OriginalQuantity { get; set; }
                public StockAdjustment StockAdjustment { get; set; }
            }



          public StockAdjustment GetAll(int Id)
            {


                oStockAdjustment = GetStockAdjustmentById(Id);

                var prepo = new ProductRepo();

                oStockAdjustment.StockAdjustmentItems = new List<StockAdjustmentItem>();


                StockAdjustmentItem ai1 = new StockAdjustmentItem();
                ai1.Id = 1 ;
                ai1.OriginalQuantity = 250;
               oStockAdjustment.StockAdjustmentItems.Add(ai1);



                StockAdjustmentItem ai2 = new StockAdjustmentItem();
                ai2.Id = 1;
                ai2.OriginalQuantity = 375;
               oStockAdjustment.StockAdjustmentItems.Add(ai2);

                return oStockAdjustment;

            }
```

Now I have controller Code

```
 public ActionResult Index(string searchContent = "")
        {
            AdjustmentRepo oAdjustmentRepo = new AdjustmentRepo();

            var adjustments = from adjustment in oAdjustmentRepo.GetAll() select adjustment;


            ViewBag.StockAdjustmentList = adjustments;
            return View(adjustments);
        }
```

This Working perfectly fine...

Now, the problem comes when, I am trying to show StockAdjustment in List.

I have to show the sum of the OriginalQuantites of StockAdjustmentItems in the Front of StockAdjustment item in grid.

in above Exmaple I want to show 650(250 + 375) in the row of a gird.

```
  @model IEnumerable<StockWatchServices.DomainClass.StockAdjustment>

      @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
        {            
     columns.Add(c=>c.StockAdjustmentItems.Sum( OriginalQuantity ???? Im stuck here... ) 
        }
```

What should I write here ?

I can see like this...
[image]

Comment: Do you also want to include **250+375** in your sum?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...yes I want to show the sum...

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope you will get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a getter only property on the `StockAdjustment` class

```
public class StockAdjustment
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public List<StockAdjustmentItem> StockAdjustmentItems { get; set; } 
 public int SumOfStockAdjustmentItemQuantity
 {
  get 
  { 
   if (this.StockAdjustmentItems != null)
   {
    return this.StockAdjustmentItems.Sum(s=>s.OriginalQuantity);
   }
   return 0;
 }
}
```

}

And then in your Razor view:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
{            
 columns.Add(c => c.SumOfStockAdjustmentItemQuantity) 
}
```

Comment: No, It method get called before the assigning values to the Class object.

Comment: StockAdjustment shows null so it doesnt sum up StockAdjustmentItems

Comment: that is not related to the getter property.. check your Index action.. isn't that sending a proper list of StockAdjustments to the view..

Comment: List is coming to view properly, but it StockAdjustment  is null. why dont we pass parameter to the SumOfStockAdjustmentItemQuantity this method ?

Comment: what do you mean by list is coming to view properly? do you see an element in it.. try to print Model.Count() in the Razor view and see the count.

Comment: ya, its coming properly... I can see the values in other columns...what change we have to make in code so we can pass the parameter to that method ?

Comment: stange.. what is the count of StockAdjustmentItems and values in OriginalQuantity

Comment: StockAdjustment objects itself is null when we called SumOfStockAdjustmentItemQuantity this method, I think we should pass the parameter to it...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below code :

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.StockAdjustmentItems.Where(quantity => quantity.OriginalQuantity != null).Sum(sum => sum.OriginalQuantity).ToString());
})
```